# SAS - How to select random samples based on condition

Tags: sas, sampling

I have a SAS data set that contains a column of numbers ranging from -2000 to 4000.
I want to select 37 random samples based on the following conditions.
If num between -2000 to -1000, randomly select 10 samples from this range,
if num between -1000 to 0, randomly select 15 sample from this range,
if num between 0 to 1000, randomly select 12 samples from this range,

I've tried the following:

```
proc surveyselect data=save.table
   method=srs n=37 out=save.table_sample seed=1953;
run;
```

But this would give me random 37 samples from the whole population.  I want to randomly select according the data range.

Please help with SAS code, thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Did you try running three times each time with a different where clause?

Comment: Richard, I proposed something that is essentially the same. Where clause will be actually more cleaner since we can avoid the datastep altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a grouping variable in your data set that you can use to group analysis.

   ```
   data output;
   set save.table;
   if number < -1000 then group=1;
   else if number < 0 then group=2;
   else if number < 1000 then group=3;
   run;
   ```
2. Use PROC SURVEYSELECT with either a data set that has the same variable, GROUP, as well as the sample size or list the sample size in the PROC SURVEYSELECT.

   ```
   proc surveyselect data=output
   method=srs n=37 out=save.table_sample seed=1953 sampsize=(37 15 12);
   strata group;
   run;
   ```

Couldn't test because no sample data was provided, so here's an example using SASHELP.HEART

```
proc sort data=sashelp.heart out=heart; by chol_status; run;


proc surveyselect data=heart (where=(not missing(chol_status))) method=srs sampsize=(5 10 15) out=want;
strata chol_status;
run;
```

Comment: Computing a strata value is real smart.  From helps `"The STRATA statement names one or more variables that partition the input data set into nonoverlapping groups (strata)"`, and `"The formatted values of the STRATA variables determine the STRATA variable levels."` and `"The STRATA variables function much like BY variables, and PROC SURVEYSELECT expects the input data set to be sorted by the STRATA variables. The BY statement options DESCENDING and NOTSORTED are available in the STRATA statement."`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue to use `proc surveyselect`, then a simple way to do this is:

```
data set1 set2 set3;
  set save.table;
  if number < -1000 then output set1;
  else if number < 0 then output set2;
  else if number < 1000 then output set3;
run;
```

Then call `proc surveyselect` thrice with different n values on these 3 datasets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes this could work! However, I'm just demonstrating my question using a small example. In reality, I need to separate and sample data for 20 times (not 3 in this case). So, do you know any other better way except for creating 20 data sets? Thanks again

Comment: If calling ````proc surveyselect```` 20 times is an option, then what Richard proposed  in his comments is a better way of doing the same thing. If not, I can propose a different method just using a single datastep.

Comment: Please propose a single datastep. It would be more efficient and it's a good thing for me to learn. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: It's possible a format would be respected so you could try that with my solution if you want to drop the extra data step.